# Helm-Charts provide a list as a parameter

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

My custom Helm chart contains a variable which is taking strings list as a parameter,

**values.yaml**

```
myList: []
```

I need to pass the **myList** as a parameter,

```
helm upgrade --install myService  helm/my-service-helm  --set myList=[string1,string2]
```

Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: See [The Format and Limitations of `--set`](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of-set) in the Helm documentation.  (A little tricky to find, admittedly, but it's spelled out there.)

Comment: The new link is [The Format and Limitations of `--set`](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of-set).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array values can be specified using curly braces: --set foo={a,b,c}.

From: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1987

Answer (score 2):

In addition please take a look at [**escape characters**](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of-set):

```
--set foo={a\,b\,c}
```